# Translate templates in django

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I have project in Django 1.8.
I want to have website with 3 languages, but when I choose language nothing happen:

Code in my template:

```
    {% load i18n %}

    ...

<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
    {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
    {% for language in languages %}
    <a href="{% url 'set_language' %}">{{ language.code }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
</form>
```

My urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'website.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'', include("www.urls", namespace="www")),
    url(r'^blog/', include("blog.urls", namespace="blog")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
)
```

My settings (locale) - I use here django-rosetta:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('pl', u'Poland'),
    ('en', u'US'),
    ('ru', u'Russia'),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Build-in django set_language view accepts POST requests with `language` code as parateter. Clicking on the `a` tag even within form view does GET request.

Change your template to following

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <select name="language">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view

Comment: This version 1.8 worked but the one in the 3.0 documentation didn't. Thank you for it.